# Attach a checkbox javascript to a class

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have done 7 check boxes and code them to only one should be checked, and here is the code:

```
        $j(document).ready(function(){
        $j(':checkbox').bind('change', function() {
            var thisClass = $j(this).attr('class');
            if ($j(this).attr('checked')) {
                $j(':checkbox.' + thisClass + ":not(#" + this.id + ")").removeAttr('checked');
            }
            else {
                $j(this).attr('checked', false);
                $j('.first-image').show();
                $j('.hide-onload').hide();
            }
        });
    });
```

and I had to create another 2 check boxes in the same page to choose between "yes" or "no" and they have another class

everything is fine except when I check the "Yes" "No" boxes it should not uncheck the first checked box because it is in different class.

The question is: How to make the code I have attach to work only with the class of the first 7 check boxes and make another one for the "Yes" "No" check boxes.

I hope I was clear enough, and here is the page link I am working on it that explains the problem http://www.cabas-durables.fr/magento/index.php/custom-contact/

Thank you in advance ....

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can separate your responsabilities with two additional classes:

```
$j('.normal-checkboxes:checkbox').bind(...);
$j('.yes-no:checkbox').bind(...);
```

And then wrap your checkboxes like this:

```
<div class="normal-checkboxes">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox">
</div>

<div class="yes-no">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox">
</div>
```

**EDIT:**

```
$j(document).ready(function(){
    // When clicking a .normal-checkboxes..
    $j('.normal-checkboxes:checkbox').bind('click', function() {
        // Remove the property checked for all normal-checkboxes
        $('.normal-checkboxes:checkbox').prop('checked', false);
        // Add the property checked to the clicked one
        $(this).prop('checked', true);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you rusban for you answer, I have tried that, `$j('.roundedOne:checkbox').bind('change', function()` but now all the boxes can be checked without unchecking, I need only one to be checked from 7 checkboxes

Comment: Maybe you would like to use radio buttons instead of checkboxes. http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_radio

Comment: That might be a great solution, Thank you, I will try that now, and I will leave the first code for 7 check boxes as it is and do radio buttons for yes and no, then it will not get conflict in the page, but I will lose the check boxes style I have done for yes and no like the first 7 boxes

Comment: I updated my answer. This should do checkboxes works as radio buttons.

Comment: Hi Rusben, I used your updated answer, but I don't know why it is not working I still can select all the checkboxes, only my code is working but whenever I do any thing to it to add the class as you told me it start selecting all, strange

Comment: if you want you can check the page: http://www.cabas-durables.fr/magento/index.php/custom-contact/

Comment: I try also radio buttons, but also they get check together

Comment: Radio buttons solution is worked fine when I gave them same name attribute, Thank you very much Rusbin